# not able to install ruby-opencv gem

Tags: ruby, opencv

I am unable to install ruby-opencv gem.

Here's what I have done so far.

Installed openCV with

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

Then tried installing ruby-opencv gem with

```
gem install ruby-opencv
```

But I got the following error

```
➜  test  gem install ruby-opencv
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-opencv:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>> Check the required libraries...
checking for main() in -lopencv_calib3d... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_contrib... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_core... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_features2d... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_flann... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_gpu... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby
    --with-opencv-dir
    --without-opencv-dir
    --with-opencv-include
    --without-opencv-include=${opencv-dir}/include
    --with-opencv-lib
    --without-opencv-lib=${opencv-dir}/lib
    --with-libxml2-dir
    --without-libxml2-dir
    --with-libxml2-include
    --without-libxml2-include=${libxml2-dir}/include
    --with-libxml2-lib
    --without-libxml2-lib=${libxml2-dir}/lib
    --with-opencv_calib3dlib
    --without-opencv_calib3dlib
    --with-opencv_contriblib
    --without-opencv_contriblib
    --with-opencv_corelib
    --without-opencv_corelib
    --with-opencv_features2dlib
    --without-opencv_features2dlib
    --with-opencv_flannlib
    --without-opencv_flannlib
    --with-opencv_gpulib
    --without-opencv_gpulib
extconf.rb:53:in `block in <main>': libopencv_gpu not found. (RuntimeError)
    from extconf.rb:52:in `each'
    from extconf.rb:52:in `<main>'
```

It seems there is no libopencv-gpu dependency installed.

I tried to install it with apt-get but couldn't succeed as no repository was found.

Can any one help me how to install ruby-opencv gem?

UPDATE
added mkmf.log content

```
➜  test  cat /home/ckgagan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/ruby-opencv-0.0.11/ext/opencv/mkmf.log
have_library: checking for main() in -lopencv_calib3d... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby -lopencv_calib3d  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:53: error: ‘main’ undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:4:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:4:28: warning: variable ‘p’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby -lopencv_calib3d  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘main’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { main(); return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for main() in -lopencv_contrib... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lopencv_calib3d  '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:53: error: ‘main’ undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:4:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:4:28: warning: variable ‘p’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lopencv_calib3d  '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘main’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { main(); return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for main() in -lopencv_core... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:53: error: ‘main’ undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:4:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:4:28: warning: variable ‘p’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘main’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { main(); return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for main() in -lopencv_features2d... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:53: error: ‘main’ undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:4:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:4:28: warning: variable ‘p’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘main’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { main(); return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for main() in -lopencv_flann... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby -lopencv_flann -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:53: error: ‘main’ undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:4:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:4:28: warning: variable ‘p’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby -lopencv_flann -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘main’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { main(); return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for main() in -lopencv_gpu... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lopencv_flann -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_flann -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:53: error: ‘main’ undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:4:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:4:28: warning: variable ‘p’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -Wl,-R/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lopencv_flann -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -L/home/ckgagan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib -lruby -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_flann -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_calib3d  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘main’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_gpu
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { main(); return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: what show the mkmf.log? and why can't you install the `libopencv_gpu` dev?

Comment: I am sorry where does mkmf.log resides :). I searched it in /var/log directory but it not there.

Comment: it shell be resided in the build folder: but try to find with `find ~/ -name mkmf.log`

Comment: added the content of mkmf.log under UPDATE section

Comment: I used sudo apt-get install libopencv-gpu-dev but it returned me  Unable to locate package libopencv-gpu-dev.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 13.04 LTS.

Comment: i've found this package: http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-13.10/ubuntu-universe-i386/libopencv-gpu-dev_2.4.5+dfsg-0ubuntu4_i386.deb.html and 
http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-13.10/ubuntu-universe-i386/libopencv-gpu-dev_2.4.5+dfsg-0ubuntu4_i386.deb.html

Answer (score 3):

I just successfully install this gem ruby-opencv after hours investigation with many failures.

You have to download 2.x archive from http://opencv.org/downloads.html, NOTE, you can't install the latest version which is 3.0.beta, I'm the one who downloaded 3.0.beta initially, and got many failures.

Then install required packages and make install opencv according to this instruction 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation

From this installation instruction, you don't need to build opencv_contrib, just build opencv, that's all.

Finally, execute gem i ruby-opencv

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Xiaohui, I'm going through this process right now. Could you say more about not needing to build opencv_contrib vs. normal opencv? It looks like the link to the documents is broken and there is no reference to this difference in the install docs I found on the same site.

Comment: Follow your guide, RVM reinstall ruby version, then install(brew installl opencv) and ruby-opencv(bundle install), done!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the gem with the path to your opencv install as per the instructions on their [github page](https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv).

```
gem install ruby-opencv -- --with-opencv-dir=/path/to/opencvdir
```

Answer (score 0):

@lan Delairre, this is my note while installing opencv, hope this is helpful to you:

Download opencv-2.4.10 from http://opencv.org/downloads.html

Build libs

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation

If got some error, try follow this instruction to install packages

http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev

cd ~/src/opencv-2.4.10
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -DWITH_QT=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DFORCE_VTK=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_GDAL=ON -DWITH_XINE=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
make -j7
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: 2.4.11 seems a better option in many cases, because old versions of gcc fail to compiler 2.4.10